# powershell list all active domain users with group membership

Tags: powershell

How can I get a list of all active domain users with group membership and one user per line?

I have tried:

```
Import-Module Activedirectory
Get-ADUser -Filter 'enabled -eq $true' -Properties SamAccountname,DisplayName,memberof | % {
New-Object PSObject -Property @{
UserName = $_.DisplayName
Groups = ($_.memberof | Get-ADGroup | Select -ExpandProperty Name) -join 
","}
} | Select SamAccountname,UserName,Groups
```

but SamAccountname is empty.

Comment: That's a lot of pipes. Does the first command work as expected?

Comment: yes, i get listing of username and groups,  but SamAccountname field impty on all lines

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't have `SamAccountname` because powershell searchs this property in your custom object which you create with New-`Object`.
If you want to retrieve `SamAccountname` in this object you must modify to have :

```
Get-ADUser -Filter 'enabled -eq $true' -Properties SamAccountname,DisplayName,memberof | % {
New-Object PSObject -Property @{
UserName = $_.DisplayName
oSamAccountname= $_.SamAccountname
Groups = ($_.memberof | Get-ADGroup | Select -ExpandProperty Name) -join 
","}
} | Select oSamAccountname,UserName,Groups
```

Answer (score 2):

This is fairly simple code, but it gave me a list of Users and their group memberships.
I had to sort the results to get it looking as I wanted, but this does result in CSV file format, which makes it easier to manipulate in Excel.

```
$ADGroupList = Get-ADGroup -Filter * | Select Name -ExpandProperty Name | Sort Name
ForEach($Group in $ADGroupList)
{
  $members=Get-ADGroupMember -Identity $Group | Select Name, SAMAccountName | Sort
  ForEach($member in $members)
  {
  Write-Host ($member.Name + "," + $member.SAMAccountName  + "," + $Group.name)
  }
}
```